# Canvas coordinates and collision in JS(Snake)

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im coding Snake from JS via this tutorial: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/think-like-a-programmer-how-to-build-snake-using-only-javascript-html-and-css-7b1479c3339e

But Im not that familiar with Canvas.

In two functions, one for collision and one for creating the food there's the following code that I need explained:

```
function didGameEnd() {
    for (let i = 4; i < snake.length; i++) {
        if (snake[i].x === snake[0].x && snake[i].y === snake[0].y) return true
    }
    const hitLeftWall = snake[0].x < 0;
    const hitRightWall = snake[0].x > gameCanvas.width - 10;
    const hitToptWall = snake[0].y < 0;
    const hitBottomWall = snake[0].y > gameCanvas.height - 10;
    return hitLeftWall || hitRightWall || hitToptWall || hitBottomWall
}
```

In the function didGameEnd Im wondering what this stands for:
"< 0;" & "> gameCanvas.width - 10;" ? Im thinking the coordinates for the canvas but I can't really find a clear answer.
and also:

```
function createFood() {
    foodX = randomTen(15, gameCanvas.width - 10);
    foodY = randomTen(15, gameCanvas.height - 10);
    generate a new food location
    snake.forEach(function isFoodOnSnake(part) {
        const foodIsoNsnake = part.x == foodX && part.y == foodY;
        if (foodIsoNsnake) createFood();
    });
}
```

And for createFood its also "gameCanvas.width - 10" and why it says 15 before ?

Comment: `hitRightWall = snake[0].x > gameCanvas.width - 10`... `gameCanvas.width` is the width of the canvas in pixel, the `-10` is because the snake has a width of 10px, and `snake[0].x` is the leftmost pixel of the snake. I don't know the second question (in the article its `randomTen(0, gameCanvas.width - 10);` and not `15` maybe a typo?)

Comment: How is this related to CSS ?

Comment: @RolandStarke yes you're right! about the typo!! Thank you :)

Comment: @ZohirSalak well yeah you're right this question isn't, I didn't think about the fact that in the tutorial its only js but not in my code. But it isnt relevant for the question.